# How can I focus on the current document window on SQL Server Management Studio without Mouse?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio, I can Move to the next tool window By hit Alt+F6.
After that, How can I focus on the current document window without using Mouse?

[Official Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205) says that：

> [Esc] Key Close a menu or dialog box, cancels an operation in progress, or focuses on the current document window.

certainly, I often focus on the current document window By [Esc], but In many cases It doesn't work.
Why doesn't It work, and How can I do that well??

I use SSMS 2012 Express.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> is the key for focus on document window in SQLServer 2008.